# Facebook Profile url from id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

To generate user's profile from id, which is the right way in following?

1. http://facebook.com/profile.php?id=ID
   Working but for some users, getting error "Profile Unavailable 
   Sorry, this profile is not available at the moment. Please try again shortly."
2. http://www.facebook.com/ID
   Working but not sure if it will work for all users

Is there any robust way to do this, with graph api or any other way?

Answer (score 1):

www.facebook.com/ID works for any Facebook Graph API Object, including users, pages, posts, photos and videos.

e.g.

- https://www.facebook.com/19292868552 will take you to the Facebook Developers Page
- https://www.facebook.com/10151403325753553 will take you to the profile pic of the above page

Answer (score 0):

http://www.facebook.com/ID is the new way, and it works for all IDs I have used. profile.php is the old way (when FB URLs didn't use to be clean) and its still supported, but /ID should always work.

Comment: I think app-scoped IDs are not being discussed. Can you confirm app-scoped IDs will work with http://facebook.com/profile.php?id=ID ?

Comment: Profile_ids are app-scoped since V2.0, so I'm surprised that you think they're out of question

Comment: I understand that. What I really meant is if you consider app-scoped IDs, then either of the above 2 methods should not work. So if the OP is saying "Working but for some users", then this definitely mean he is considering actual IDs and not app-scoped IDs.